# Object doesn't support property or method 'igTree' error when running Infragistics Tree Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, infragistics

I am trying to set up a tree view using an entity framework data object (EF 6 in MVC 5). I've run into a problem when I try to Render() my tree.... I receive the 'Object doesn't support property or method 'igTree'' error.

My code to set up the tree (in my view):

```csh
@(Html.Infragistics()
      .Tree()
      .Bindings(bindings =>
      {
          bindings.
          TextKey("L1Name").
          PrimaryKey("L1TODSID").
          ValueKey("L1TODSID").
          ChildDataProperty("L2Name").
          Bindings(b1 =>
          {
              b1.
              TextKey("L2Name").
              ValueKey("L2TODSID").
              PrimaryKey("L2TODSID");
          });
      })
      .DataSource(Model)
      .DataBind()
      .Render() 
)
```

I get no errors until I add in the 'Render()' call.

I read a post on the Infragistics forum asking if they will be supporting MVC 5... Are they not doing that? Is that my issue?

Also, these are my calling scripts:

```csh
    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/css/structure/infragistics.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js")"></script>


    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src=@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.core.js")></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.lob.js")></script>


   @(Html.Infragistics()
          .Loader()
          .ScriptPath("~/igniteui/js/")
          .CssPath("~/igniteui/css/")
          .Render()
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Final Resolve.

Just in case anyone else ever runs accross this situation...

I knew this error ('Object doesn't support property or method...') could be caused by jquery loading twice. Thought I had thoroughly checked all script calls. However, being new to .NET and MVC 5 (razor), I completely missed this line at the *end* of my layout page (I didn't set up the project originally):

```csh
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

So...

In the end, I was initiallizing JQuery in my script block at the top (with a call to the minified file), then I was calling it again, which is what caused the error.

A big thanks to @nemesv, because the fact that he explained the loading process in greater detail than I could find online gave me the confidence to know that I was doing things correctly on that side. Then I just needed to hunt down the second call to initialize JQ.

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you checked in your browsers network tab that your `~/igniteui/js/infragistics.core.js` and `~/igniteui/js/infragistics.lob.js` are correctly loaded? Where do you have your script references? In your layout? In the `head` tag or in the body? If in the body where after the `@RenderBody()`?

Comment: You can only get this error if the `infragistics.lob.js` not correctly loaded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### By default (if you are not using the loader infrastructure)

The `.Render()` call will render the following HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {$('#Tree1').igTree({ dataSource: ... });});
 </script>
```

So you get the exception on the `igTree` function call which would initialize the tree.

Your `igTree` function can be undefined:

- If you are not loading the necessary igniteui scripts:

  ```
  <script src=@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.core.js")></script>
  <script src=@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.lob.js")></script>
  ```

  **Make sure that these scripts are included in your view or in your Layour file**
- If you are not using the rigth path or the scripts file are not there on the server:

  **Check for broken link in your browsers network console (F12 in IE/Chrome FireBug in FF):**

  [image]

  If you 404 error next to your script you will know that they are not loaded correctly and you need to fix the paths.
- If you are referencing jQuery more than once can cause this error too:

  Foe example you have the `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>` in a partial which is loaded by Ajax multiple times, etc.

  **Make sure that you are referencing all your scripts once.**

### In the case of using the `loader`

When using the Loader infrasturure the `.Render()` call will render the a different HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ig.loader('igTree', function() {$('#Tree1').igTree({ dataSource: });});
</script>
```

So the loader will load the necessary script required by the tree so you don't need to include `infragistics.core.js` and `infragistics.lob.js`.
When using the loader in theory you could not the get the exception.

But if you call: `@(Html.Infragistics().Loader()...` **after** your `Html.Infragistics().Tree()` then the MVC wrapper does not that you are using the loader so it renders the HTML like when you don't use the loader so if you rightfully not referenced the  `infragistics.core.js` and `infragistics.lob.js`. then you get the exception even if you are "using" the loader.

**So make sure that you call `@(Html.Infragistics().Loader()...` before using any of the `Infragistics` controls.**

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue with MVC 4 and Ignite UI. Removing @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
from the _Layout.cshtml resolved the issue.